# Gtk::AboutDialog crash when clicking on URL

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I am working with GTKmm 3, MSYS2, MinGW (GCC 5.3.1) under Windows 7.

I made a Glade interface with a normal window and a Gtk::AboutDialog.

All is working OK, but when opening the About dialog and clicking on its URL link, then the next error occours and the program exits:

```
(GladeTest1.exe:3440): GLib-CRITICAL **: unquote_string_inplace: assertion 'err == NULL || *err == NULL' failed
```

This is the code:

```
Gtk::Window *window1;
Gtk::AboutDialog *aboutDialog1;

builder->get_widget("window1", window1);
builder->get_widget("aboutdialog1", aboutDialog1);

aboutDialog1->set_transient_for(*window1);
aboutDialog1->show();
```

Using Dr. Mingw debugger I got this traces:

```
GladeTest1.exe caused an Access Violation at location 000000000070255A in module libgtk-3-0.dll Reading from location 0000000000000008.

Loading symbols... done.

Registers:
eax=00000000 ebx=03d5c1a8 ecx=00000000 edx=00000001 esi=024d8020 edi=00000016
eip=0070255a esp=0028ea9c ebp=0028eb54 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00210216

AddrPC   Params
0070255A 02514D30 03B36FA0 0250FB00  libgtk-3-0.dll!gtk_search_entry_handle_event
0082845C 0257C900 0028EC84 00000002  libgtk-3-0.dll!gtk_main_do_event
63C45FD2 0028ED9C 0028ED00 0028EDBC  libgobject-2.0-0.dll!g_closure_invoke
63C5F31A 025025A8 025297B0 00000000  libgobject-2.0-0.dll!g_signal_emit_valist
6883689B 025297B0 00000000 02514D30  libglib-2.0-0.dll!g_mutex_unlock
025025A8 00000000 02514D30 00000000
025297B0 02514D30 00000000 00000000
```

It seems like there is some problem with libgtk-3-0.dll or libglib DLL.

I am looking for an answer for 2 days without success.

Something important is missing?

Anybody has a clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We had the same errors/crashes under WinXP64 and Win7/G4 with MSys2/MingW 6.2.0 using Gtk+ ( i.e. Gtk2).

However, when we compiled/build our own Gtk/Gdk libs via MingW, exactly the same Gtk_About dialog's Http link worked.

... this seems to point the finger at something in the MSys2 build.  Indeed, when trying to build Gtk following the MSys2 "pkg build directions" also fails (at least for us).

... we haven't had too much "luck" communicating with the MSys2 people.

... Instead, we use the so-called "Ingar Build" approach found here (http://ingar.satgnu.net/devenv/mingw32/gtk.html).  His instructions are for the entire build from the ground up, which is a few day's work, but it is very much worth it for us ... and provides massively more control and flexibility compared to MSys2.

P.S. You will need to make a few adjustments to Ingar's instructions for Gtk3.  Also, if you build the packages with versions much later/newer compared to those on Ingar's site, additional packages will be required (due to the additional dependencies in newer versions).